# How do I know which image the user clicked?

Tags: php, html

I am setting up a new website and I want to be able to detect which pizza the user clicked on the OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html and echo the name of the pizza that was clicked onto the ShoppingCart.php.

I have tried creating a form, but I cannot create a form because the task requirement is that I cannot use a form and the user must click on the image. I have tried to use get and post but does not work without form.

**OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online Pizza Ordering Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Online Pizza Ordering Page</h1>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img src="supreme.jpg" 
        width="82" height="86" title="Detailed sauce and quantity page" 
        alt="Supreme"></a>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img src="meatlover.jpg" 
        width="82" height="86" title="Detailed sauce and quantity page" 
        alt="Meatlover"></a>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img src="hawaii.jpg" 
        width="82" height="86" title="Detailed sauce and quantity page" 
        alt="Hawaii"></a>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img src="fourseasons.jpg" 
        width="82" height="86" title="Detailed sauce and quantity page" alt="Four 
        Seasons"></a>
        <a href="Detailedsauceandquantitypage.html"><img src="vege.jpg" width="82" 
        height="86" title="Detailed sauce and quantity page" alt="Vege"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ShoppingCart.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopping Cart page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Shopping Cart page</h1>
        <?php
        // define variables and set to empty values
        $bbqPizza = $tomatoPizza = $salsaPizza = "";

        if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
            $bbq = $_POST["bbqPizza"];
            $tomato = $_POST["tomatoPizza"];
            $salsa = $_POST["salsaPizza"];
            echo $bbq . " pizzas with bbq sauce, " . $tomato . " pizzas with tomato sauce and " . $salsa . " pizzas with salsa sauce.";
        }
        ?>
        <br>
        <a href="OnlinePizzaOrderingPage.html">Add more pizzas to cart</a>
        <a href="Checkoutpage.html">Go to checkout</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expected the Checkoutpage.html to be able to echo the pizza name corresponding to the pizza image that the user clicked on in Online Pizza Ordering Page. The actual results is nothing.

Comment: Previously I learned that if I have a submit button with a name attached to it I can post data easily however this time I want to post without that submit button and without a form. I want to be able to retrieve data only by checking what image the user has clicked.

Comment: Do you guys think I could use document.getElementById("pizzaform").submit();

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this purpose

```
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var img_title = $('img', this).attr('title');
    alert(img_title);
 });
});
```

For javascript you need to pass title in function in every img tag like this

```
<img src="supreme.jpg" 
width="82" height="86" title="Detailed sauce and quantity page" 
alt="Supreme" onclick="imageTitle(this.title);">
```

Then in javascript

```
<script>
function imageTitle(title){
 alert(title);
 console.log(title);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is there another method? I can only use javascript, css, php and html.

Comment: without Jquery?

Comment: Yes, I can only use javascript, css, php and html. Those four languages are the only ones allowed and the only ones I have been taught.

Comment: So I do I put the javascript on the ShoppingCart.php page?

Comment: I think you just need to embed javascript function in script tags like I have done

Comment: Like I need the statement to print data from javascript and I need it to print inside of the php code: echo $bbq . " (javascript returning the name of the pizza) pizzas with bbq sauce, " . $tomato . " (javascript returning the name of the pizza) pizzas with 
tomato sauce and " . $salsa . " (javascript returning the name of the pizza) pizzas with salsa sauce.";

Comment: Okay I give it a try.

Comment: No that doesn't work the way I wanted it to. It just displays an alert on the page. I want it to be able to output two pages after. Like after the user clicks the image he will have to select the sauce and quatity from the next page which is working perfectly. And all the items in the shopping cart will show on the third page however I am having trouble collecting the pizza that the user chosen and printing it on the third page which is the ShoppingCart.php.